# Anchor list of blog posts (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to create an anchor list of all my blog posts. The list is supposed to be on the top of the blog page. When I add a new post, the anchor link should be added automatacly.

**Like this:
I got a page with all my blog posts and I want a list of all the posts at the top. "First post" anchor link should link to the heading of the First post on the *same page*. And so on.**

I've tried various plugins but they seem to only create an anchor list inside a blog post or on a page. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$posts=get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1));
//list post titles 
echo '<ul>';
foreach($posts as $post){ 
    $post_title = $post->post_title;
    echo "<li><a href='#$post_title' title='$post_title'>$post_title</a></li>";
}
echo '</ul>';

//now list post contents to be linked on the same page
echo '<div>';
foreach($posts as $post){
    $post_title = $post->post_title;
    $content = $post->post_content;
    //echo "<h3 id='$post_title' title='$post_title'>$post_title</h3>";
    echo "<p id='$post_title'> $content </p>";
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Is there posible to link the anchors to each post's div instead? (I want to hide the headings)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach(get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1)) as $mypost) //Gets all posts
{
    $post_url = get_permalink($mypost->ID);
    $post_title = $mypost->post_title;
    echo "<li><a href='$post_url' title='$post_title'>$post_title</a></li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Insert this in your theme file wherever you want to generate your post list.  Setting the `numberposts` option on `get_posts` to -1 returns all of your blog's posts.

Comment: This gives me a list of links to each blog post. I want an anchor link. If I got a page with all my blogposts i want an anchor list on the top of the page, when you click on one of the links you get to an anchor. You stay on the same page and you are only sent further down (just above each heading).